# Is it possible to access raw github code by tag name?

Tags: git, github

Does anyone know if it's possible to remotely retrieve raw github content defined by a tag?

Example:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/tags/some-tag/file.ext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the path format is `/user/repo/tag-or-branch/file`.

For example, Python's license with tag `v3.8.5`:
[/python/cpython/v3.8.5/LICENSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/v3.8.5/LICENSE)

and on the branch `master`: [/python/cpython/master/LICENSE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/master/LICENSE)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, drop the `branch/tags/` from your example:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/some-tag/file.ext

For example, this link works:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dense-analysis/ale/v2.7.0/README.md